# Is it possible to add a new XML tag so that it's transparent for an XSD validation?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xml-validation

A have an XSD schema that describes an XML object (simplified example):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://my-custom-ns.com">
    <xs:element name="item">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="active" type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

That schema is built-in in an app as a resource and installed on many workstations.
The app consumes XML files and validates them against this schema.
Here is an (simplified) example of such an XML:

```
<my:item xmlns:my="http://my-custom-ns.com">
    <active>true</active>
    <value>foo</value>
</my:item>
```

Now, I want my XML files to get a new element (a new tag) without changing the XSD:

```
<my:item xmlns:my="http://my-custom-ns.com">
    <active>true</active>
    <value>foo</value>
    <tag>bar</tag>
</my:item>
```

I'm not changing the XSD, so obviously the validation fails on a new tag.
Is there a way for having a new tag in the XML so that it "passes through" the validation transparently (i.e. gets completely ignored)?

I tried adding a new namespace in the XML in the hope that the XSD validation will ignore it, but that didn't help:

```
<my:item xmlns:my="http://my-custom-ns.com" xmlns:new="http://new-ns.com">
    <active>true</active>
    <value>foo</value>
    <new:tag>bar</new:tag>
</my:item>
```

The background is: it should be possible for the current app version to process XML files that have an additional tag, simple ignoring it. But the app has a strong validation against an XSD, as I described above. Maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: How would your application see that new item if it would be in a different namespace? I believe this is hardly possible without schema modification.

Comment: @AlexeyR., the namespace was just an (unlucky) example. Actually I need a way to make a tag fully transparent to the XSD validation against a schema that doesn't explicitly allow *undefined* tags. Seems to be impossible, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. There is a way to achieve this if the original schema has a special tag.

If you know in advance that documents may have extra elements, but you do not know these elements in advance, then schemas can be designed in a forward-compatible way using `xs:any` tags, like so:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://my-custom-ns.com">
    <xs:element name="item">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="active" type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This document is valid against the above schema:

```
<my:item xmlns:my="http://my-custom-ns.com" xmlns:new="http://new-ns.com">
    <active>true</active>
    <value>foo</value>
</my:item>
```

as well as this one:

```
<my:item xmlns:my="http://my-custom-ns.com" xmlns:new="http://new-ns.com">
    <active>true</active>
    <value>foo</value>
    <new:tag>bar</new:tag>
</my:item>
```

The behavior of `xs:any` can be adapted by changing the values of the `namespace` and `processContents` attributes.

However, if the schema is already done, and is outside of your control, then extra elements can only appear if allowed by the original designer.

An example of this is... XML Schema itself. XML Schema elements may contain arbitrary attributes in foreign namespaces (several standards are built on XML Schema that way), and this is because the XML Schema of Schemas explicitly allows attributes in other namespaces.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about using the `xs:any` schema element. But unfortunately the schema is already on the target machines and cannot be changed without upgrading the app version (which is not possible due to special reasons). And apparently, the original schema designer didn't allow using extra elements...

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer would be to restructure the XML instance. XML Schema allows nesting schema-validated XML (without modification) in a bigger instance.

```
<new:wrapper xmlns:my="http://my-custom-ns.com" xmlns:new="http://new-ns.com">
  <my:item>
    <active>true</active>
    <value>foo</value>
  </my:item>
  <new:tag>bar</new:tag>
</new:wrapper>
```

This can be achieved with a new schema that imports the former one and references the element `my:item`.

The former schema does not need any modification as long as the nested XML strictly validates against it.

Comment: Well, that would be possible if I could provide the new schema to the app users. But unfortunately, the app version cannot be upgraded due to special reasons, so I'm stuck with the old one.